# Unity can't reload scene properly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wanna ***restart the scene***, I have a countdown timer in there.
I've tried to `LoadScene()` but the countdown timer is ***still in the current time before I restart the scene***

[image]

[image]

```
  {
        TheTimer();

        if (stoptimer == true)
        {
            GetComponent<RandomSpawner>().enabled = false;

            textPoin.text = "Total Poin: " + playerObj.GetComponent<Player>().point.ToString();

            playerObj.GetComponent<Player>().enabled = false;
            Destroy(spawnHereObject);
            panelEnd.SetActive(true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: No, I using Update()

Comment: I put this function on my Update() function ```public void TheTimer()
    {
        float time = gameTime - Time.time;
    }```

Comment: ohh, all right.

Comment: And in another case, I'm trying to go to MainMenu Scene, then I Load my GamePlay Scene again. Timer still in current time and continue the countdown

Comment: On my ```Update()``` function. gameTime is variable ``` private float gameTime```

Comment: Ok, But there is a problem when I insert my full Code. So I just can upload the screenshot

Comment: oke, there is it

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem, It's just because on Update Function and using Time.time instead Time.realtimeSinceStartup